# Color a world map based on the frequency of occurrence in each region

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a type of heatmap.

I have a shapefile of the biogeographic realms of the world, which were downloaded here:
https://www.gislounge.com/terrestrial-ecoregions-gis-data/

I created a map using the following code:

```
ggplot()+
geom_sf(data = mapa, aes(fill = REALM), alpha=0.5)
```

[The map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSfuf.png)

Now, I would like to color these regions by the frequency of invasion events, according to this data:

```
Var1 <- c("Australasia", "Afrotropic", "Neartic", "Neotropic", "not applicable", "Indomalayan", "Paleartic", "Artarctica", "Oceania")
Freq <- c(70, 25, 219, 154, 7, 9, 356, 0, 0)
invasion_df <- cbind(Var1, Freq) 

invasion_df will return:
                   Var1   Freq
        1     Australian   70
        2      Ethiopian   25
        3        Neartic  219
        4    Neotropical  154
        5 not applicable    7
        6       Oriental    9
        7      Paleartic  356
        8     Antarctica    0
        9        Oceania    0
```

How do I do this? I've looked in several places and couldn't find it.

I tried a lot of stuff... I expect someone to help me. It don't seem so hard to do it, but I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong.